# Set-Cookie Response Header がユーザ設定によりブロックされる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, cookie

Railsでログイン機能を実装しています。

認証のエンドポイントで `Set-Cookie` response header を付与していますが 「ユーザ設定によりブロックされました」という警告が出て cookie が保存されません。

画像の通り cookie, path, Secure属性, SameSite属性を付与しています。

[image: ユーザ設定によりブロックされた画像]

chrome の設定が「シークレットモードでサードパーティのCookieをブロックする」になっていたため、「Cookieを全て受け入れる」に変更したところ、問題なく cookie がセットされることを確認しました。

[image: シークレット]
から、下記に変更
[image: 全てのcookie]

デフォルトの設定は「シークレットモードでサードパーティのCookieをブロックする」　であるため、この設定のままでも cookie がセットされるようにしたいと思っています。

これを実現するために何か手立てありましたらご助言いただきたいです。

環境

- Mac OS Big Sur 11.5.2(M1)
- Google Chrome 103.0.5060.53（Official Build） （arm64）

SP

- iPhone12 iOS 15.5
- Chrome 103.0.5060.63

シーケンス図
[image: 処理のフロー]

---

※**追記**
サードパーティーの cookie として判定されているのはフロントを別会社、サーバーを自分がホストしていることによって、同じDNSサーバーで運用できない点が原因かと考えています。
参考: https://blog.cloud-acct.com/posts/u-nuxt-rails-safari-cookies/

---
**※※追記**
複数の Chrome で確認したところ、 Cookie がセットされるバージョンとされないバージョンがあるようです。

- セットされる: 103.0.5060.114（Official Build） （x86_64）
- セットされない: 103.0.5060.53（Official Build） （arm64）

Comment: ユーザーがブラウザに設定した Cookie 拒否を、サーバー側から受け入れるように変更したいということですか？

Comment: はい、やりたいことはその通りです。しかし現実的ではないのでサードパーティの cookie として判定されることを避けることで、この問題を解決できるのではないか、と考えています。

Comment: エラーが表示されているときの画面のドメインとCookieをセットしようとしているドメインは完全に別ドメインですか？それとも同じドメインですか？それともサブドメインなどの関連があるドメインですか？

Comment: 状況が良く分かりませんが、普通に認証チケットをクッキーでやり取りする場合「サードパーティの cookie として判定される」は関係ないと思うのですが。Chrome の設定の「シークレットモードでサードパーティのCookieをブロックする」よりキビシイ「サードパーティの Cookie をブロックする」でも問題ないはずです。「すべての Cookie をブロックする（推奨されません）」になってませんか？

Comment: 何にせよユーザーのブラウザの Cookie の設定をサーバー側から変更することはできません。そこを何とかしようと考えるより、「サードパーティの Cookie をブロックする」の設定があるとダメな原因を見つけ、それを解決する方が良さそうだと思います。

Comment: @keitaro_so 
エラーが表示されているときの画面のドメインとCookieをセットしようとしているドメインは完全に別ドメインですか？
=> 完全に別ドメインで、全く関連性はありません

Comment: @WebSurfer 
すべての Cookie をブロックする（推奨されません）になってませんか？
=> なっていません。「Cookieを全て受け入れる」設定の時のみ Cookie がセットできます。

Comment: > 完全に別ドメインで、全く関連性はありません <=どうなっているのか理解できません。認証サーバーを使っている？　認証のプロセスをもう少し詳しく説明していただけませんか？

Comment: @WebSurfer 
>認証のプロセスをもう少し詳しく説明
別会社がホストしているフロントから自分がホストしているサーバーへ email/password を使って認証を行います。cors 設定をしているため preflight request は成功します。認証が通ったら認証サーバーから set-cookie response header を返し、cookie を set します。フロントはその cookie を使って以後のリクエストを行うことで認証状態として api を使うことができるようになる。という流れになります。

Comment: 認証サーバーを使っているということですね。以下の画像は開発環境の OpenId Connect ベースの認証サーバー (localhost:5001 ) と MVC アプリ (localhost:44351) の認証プロセスを Fiddler で見たものですが、画像の #40 の通り localhost:44351/signin-odic に要求が出て、応答の Set_Cookie で認証クッキーが返ってきています。MVC アプリのドメインでの要求で認証クッキーが返ってくるので、認証サーバーのドメインが異なっても問題ないです。 http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/image.axd?picture=2022%2f7%2f0712Fiddler.jpg 質問者さんのケースではいかがでしょう。同じようになってないと何ともならないと思うのですが。

Comment: 上のコメントを理解いただいているでしょうか？　言い方を変えると、「フロントはその cookie を使って以後のリクエストを行う」のリクエスト先はそのフロントのドメインの Web サーバーであろうと想像してますが、もしそうであれば認証サーバーのドメインで取得した「その cookie」は違うドメインのフロントの Web サーバーには送信されませんので、たとえ Chrome の設定が「Cookie をすべて受け入れる」でもダメだと思うのですが？　そういう話ではないのでしょうか？

Comment: @WebSurfer 
言葉不十分で申し訳ございません。言葉の定義含め、状況はこの図になります。
https://gyazo.com/6caa4c147c7b98278d4aa61fa606b260
また、フロントがバックエンドの認証用エンドポイント( post /auth)へリクエストを送って成功した時の response header は下記ですので、同じ状況である認識です。
https://gyazo.com/7cbac29cf137c763f0ad2cb1918fd1ea

Comment: @WebSurfer 
そして
「フロントはその cookie を使って以後のリクエストを行う」のリクエスト先はそのフロントのドメインの Web サーバーであろうと想像
-> こちらは先程の図の通り、フロントはセットされているはずの cookie を使って「バックエンドサーバーのドメイン」へとリクエストを行います。(全てのエンドポイントを保護しているため、cookieがなければ401を返します)
https://gyazo.com/6caa4c147c7b98278d4aa61fa606b260

Comment: SameSiteはNoneにしていますが、それ以外は Cookie の設定は同じかと思っております。

Comment: > 言葉の定義含め、状況はこの図になります。 gyazo.com/6caa4c147c7b98278d4aa61fa606b260 ←その画像を質問欄を編集して貼り付けていただけませんか。その図の応答の Cookie はサードパーティ製と見なされてブラウザの設定で拒否されるのが問題と理解しました。でも、質問を見るとその設定はシークレットモードの時のみ有効で、そうでないときは Cookie は保存されると思うのですが、そのあたりはどうなのですか。

Comment: @WebSurfer 添付いたしました。「追記」にも記載しましたが、改めて確認したところ Cookie がセットできる環境とできない環境がありそうです。なお、SP の場合は Chrome, Safari 共にログインできないままですのでセットされてないように思えます。

Comment: 回答しましたので回答のコメント欄にフィードバックを返してください。

Answer (score 1):

以下の図（質問者さんが質問に追加した画像にユーザーを追加しました）の構成になっていて、バックエンドからの「認証 OK なら Set-Cookie・・・」の Cookie はサードパーティ製と見なされてブラウザの設定で拒否されるのが問題と理解しました。

[image: システム構成]

何故シークレットモードを使うのか解せませんが、そういう決まりになっているのだろうと理解して・・・

> デフォルトの設定は「シークレットモードでサードパーティのCookieをブロックする」　であるため、この設定のままでも cookie がセットされるようにしたいと思っています。これを実現するために何か手立てありましたらご助言いただきたいです。

上の図の構成のままですと手立ては無いと思います。

ユーザーにブラウザの Cookie の設定を「Cookie を全て受け入れる」に変更してもらうのが唯一の解決策だと思いますが、それは許されないのでしょうから、自分が考え付くのは:

(1) 上の図の「フロント」からの応答のところで「バックエンド」にリダイレクトし、ユーザーからはファーストパーティとして「バックエンド」に要求を出し、「バックエンド」からファーストパーティ Cookie として受け取る。

(2) Cookie ベースの認証はやめて、トークンベースの認証に替える。

・・・ぐらいです。

Comment: SPのcookie問題も含め、提案いただいた(2)の対応で検討することにします。

Comment: 「SPのcookie問題」とは何ですか？

Comment: iPhone12 iOS 15.5, Chrome 103.0.5060.63, この環境で一切ログインができない問題になります。cookie を確認する術がなさそうなので cookie 周りのエラーは確認できないのですが、PCで認証したときに cookie がセットされない状況と同じ挙動をとっています。

Comment: ログインができないというのは別の問題ではないのですか？　つまり、(1) サードパーティ Cookie をブラウザが受け取ることができる、と (2) それを送信してログインできるというのは別の話で、ログインできないという (2) の問題は、まず (1) を解決できてからの話ではないのですか？　(2) には ajax, cors での問題とかありそうです。

Comment: 失礼しました。PCのChromeではログインができるのでログイン処理自体は問題ないと思っています。SPでは cookie 周りのエラーが確認できないため、挙動として「正しい認証情報を入れてもログインできない」ように見える、という意図でした。(実際、認証エンドポイントを叩いたときはバックエンドサーバに認証成功のログが流れます)この挙動は「PCでcookieが設定できなかった」場合と同じです。

Comment: このスレッドの問題・課題はタイトルにある「Set-Cookie Response Header がユーザ設定によりブロックされる」ですよね。ログインできる・できないではないはず。このスレッドのタイトルに限った議論にしてください。

Comment: はい。「SPの場合にSet-Cookie Response Header がユーザ設定によりブロックされる問題」は引き続き生じているため、この課題が解決したとはまだ言えません。